# Javascript array not joining on | (or) character

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a javascript function that is suppoed to pull back a string to search on. I am adding these strings when the dropdown list items gets marked as selected and I would like to concat this string as "item|item2" so that my search bar can search on the or statement for datatables.

When I do the join it still comes back as item,item2

Here is the code:

```
select = $('<select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" id="' + currHeaderName + '\"><option value=""></option></select>')
  .appendTo($(column.header())).on('change', function (element, checked) {
     var selected = [];
     selected.push([$(this).val()]);

     selected = selected.join("|");

     alert(selected);

     column.search(selected, true, true).draw();
});
```

Comment: Don't push an array into the array? Also, with only one element, you won't get any separators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`val()` for a `multiple` select will already be an array

Try

```
var select = $('<select class="form-control" multiple="multiple" id="' + currHeaderName + '\"><option value=""></option></select>')
  .appendTo($(column.header()))
  .on('change', function(element, checked) {

     console.log($(this).val().join('|'));    

  });
```